# Como faço para mandar um "textbox" sempre pra direita quando estiver com foco?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um `textBox` valor monetário que esta com `0,00`, quando clico para digitar um valor exemplo `12345`, ele fica `10023,45`.

Gostaria de saber como posso arrumar isso com Javascript.

Comment: Pode colocar aqui o seu código específico e como ele trata o conteudo do textBox?

Comment: Coloque o elemento que está com problema, e todo e qualquer evento que possa estar atrelado a ele...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de resolver isso é, caso o valor seja 0,00 você limpa o campo quando houver focus nele.

```
document.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('focus', function () {
    if (this.value !== '0,00') return;
    this.value = '';
}):
```

O mesmo código usando [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('input[type=text]').on('focus', function () {
    if (this.value !== '0,00') return;
    this.value = '';
}):
```

Existem outras maneiras, você pode selecionar todo o conteúdo do campo de forma que qualquer coisa digitada vai sobrescreve-lo por completo, exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('focus', function () {
    this.selectionStart = 0;
    this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
}):
```

Não esqueça de substituir o seletor `input[type=text]` por um que se adeque ao seu código, sendo este com ID, classe ou outros atributos que identifiquem o(s) campo(s) que deseja aplicar o evento.

Answer (score 0):

Elementos `html` possuem gatilhos que são disparados por meio de eventos.
No elemento do seu formulário onde o valor monetário será inserido, você pode configurar uma ação para ser executada toda vez que o conteúdo de um determinado item for alterado.

Para isso você irá utilizar o recurso **onChange**

Função javascript para formatar valores monetários

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatMoney(c, d, t){
    var n = this, 
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
       return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
     };


     function formatar(){
        valor=document.getElementById("valor").value;
        valorFormatado = formatMoney(valor, '.', ',');
        document.getElementById("valor").value = valorFormatado;

     }
</script>
```

No seu campo de texto

```
    <input id="valor" type="text" onchange="formatar()">
```

Referencia sobre a função [formatMoney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) também e utilizar o plugin [maskMoney](http://jquery-plugins.net/maskmoney-jquery-plugin-to-mask-input-as-currency), veja um exemplo

```
$("#demo3").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar o equivalente de PHP [`number_format()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/) para Javascript.

```
$("#omeuinput").keypress(function(e) {
var valor = $(this).val();
valor = number_format(valor, 2, '.', '');
$(this).val(valor);
});


function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
        var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
        return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
    };
// Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
}
if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
}
return s.join(dec);
}
```